# Check if cell has content and if so, input something in a different cell

Tags: excel, vbscript, vba

I found a VBScript that opens an certain spreadsheet in Excel 2013, adds a column and puts a name in the first row of the column.  I'm looking to see if someone can help me with a script that can do the following:

The script should check all cells in column B starting at B2.

- If B2 has something in it, then put a "1" (no quotes) in G2
- Same thing, then if B3 has something in it, put a "1" in G3
- And so on until it reaches and empty cell.

Once it hits the empty cell, the script is done.

I have the following script below. I have no idea where to start and I tried a few different things but get errors. This is the last revision where I was just trying to say "if (b2 is less than or greater than blank then J2 is = to 1) but it's probably not the correct format.

```vb
Const xlToRight = -4161 
const xlColumns = &H2 
const xlLinear = -4132 
const xlDay = 1 
Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application") 
objExcel.Visible = True 
Set objWB = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("T:\Science Data\SampleFile.xls") 
Set objSheet = objwb.Sheets("sheet") 
objSheet.Columns("J:J").Insert xlToRight 
objSheet.Cells(1, 10).Value = "GetBestMatch" 
objSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = 1
If objSheet.Cells(2,2).Value <> "" Then objSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = 1 
set Range = objSheet.Range("J1:J" & objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count) 
Range.DataSeries xlColumns, xlLinear,xlDay, 1, , False 
objwb.Save 
objwb.close
objExcel.quit
```

Thanks a lot for the suggestions.  I made the changes to the script.  Removed the `objSheet.Cells(2,10).Value = 1` line (highlighted in bold) as it was more of a duplicate.  I'm not sure if i can incorporate the following code below.  The line you gave me works great and i can type the same line repeatedly with different cell values for each row.

Wanted to see if within the `If` statement you recommended, it could add a statement to keep checking down the B row.  For example, check B3 for data and make J3 a 1 if B3 has data, then B4 and so on, and then stop adding ones to the respective J row once it hits an empty B cell.  I couldn't get anything to work with your If statement so I searched and tried a `Do` statement that I found but made some changes to it (below).

Hopefully the code below is somewhat correct. I tried it but it doesn't fill in anything.  was trying to make check B2 for data and move over 8 cells to J2 if B2 was empty, add a 1, then go down one row and back 8 to B3, then start the `Do` statement again from there.

```vb
Sub Test2()
  Range("B2").Select
  Do Until IsEmpty(ActiveCell)
    ActiveCell.Offset(0,8).select
    ActiveCell.value = 1
    ActiveCell.Offset(1,-8).select
  Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: SO is not a place where you provide requirements and other people write code for you. Show us what you have tried so far (your code) and explain what does not work as expected and we'll help you improve/fix your code.

Comment: sorry @AnsgarWiechers, I can't seem to paste it where it keeps the original formatting so it looks like one big paragraph.

Comment: Please [edit](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/30467841/edit) your question instead of posting relevant information (and particularly code) in comments.

Comment: done, i'm still learning the site..  newb ~>

Comment: The code in `Test2` looks OK, but it's VBA code, not VBScript. Take a look at my [blog post about translating VBA to VBScript](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml).

Answer (score 1):

```
if(B2<>"") then(J2="1")
```

In the above line `B2` and `J2` are (undefined) variables, when you actually want to refer to the cells B2 and J2. Use something like this for the latter:

```
If objSheet.Range("B2").Value <> "" Then objSheet.Range("J2").Value = 1
```

Note, however, that `Range("B2")` might be relative to the active cell. I find it usually safer to use the `Cells` collection:

```
If objSheet.Cells(2, 2).Value <> "" Then objSheet.Cells(2, 10).Value = 1
```

Also, this:

```
set Range = objSheet.Range("J1:J2"&objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

should probably look like this:

```
set Range = objSheet.Range("J1:J" & objSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count)
```

With that said, I **strongly** recommend you immerse yourself in a good book about VBA. Once you have a good understanding of how VBA works, [using it from VBScript](http://sdb.planetcobalt.net/vba2vbs.shtml) won't be too hard.